# Selecting Every Other Column in a dynamic Range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

TLDR: I need to alter a macro I wrote that selected a range of data based on user input. It originally used the whole range (just consecutive columns), but now needs to select every other column.
[image]
[image]

I have a sheet I'm working on where the user will input the number of years they want to look at an investment over. Basically, I have 50 years populated, and my macro hides the columns that exceed the specified number of years. Then using the remaining visible range, I have metrics that are run(Net Present Value, Internal Rate of Return). This all worked fine, but I now need to put a percentage column next to the initial data, meaning the metric formulas can't run using the consecutive ranges as they are. They need every other column of visible data.Here 
Below is my code:

```
Sub HideCol()

'Prep the sheet

Sheets("Modeling").Visible = True
Sheets("Modeling").Activate
Columns("C:AZ").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
myNum = Worksheets("InitialData").Range("LeaseTerm").Value
Range("C1").Select
numrows = Selection.Rows.Count
numColumns = Selection.Columns.Count
Selection.Resize(numrows + 0, numColumns + myNum - 1).Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

'Input dynamic calcs
'This is my problem here. calcrange selects consecutive columns, and I need to do every other
Dim calcrange As Range

Set calcrange = Union(Range("InvestmentOutlay"), Range(Range("B57"), Range("B57").End(xlToRight)))

Range("IRR").Formula = "=IRR(" & calcrange.Address & ")"

Dim npvRange As Range
Set npvRange = Range(Range("C57"), Range("C57").End(xlToRight))

Range("NPV").Formula = "=NPV(EconGrowth," & npvRange.Address & ")"

Dim outF As Range
Dim inF As Range

Set outF = Range("InvestmentOutlay")
Set inF = Range(Range("C57"), Range("C57").End(xlToRight))
Range("PB").Formula = "=PaybackPeriod(" & outF.Address & ", " & inF.Address & ")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Set calcrange = Union(Range("InvestmentOutlay"), Range(Range("B57"), Range("B57").End(xlToRight)))
```

just add every second column to the Union:

```
Dim c As Long
Set calcrange = Range("InvestmentOutlay")
For c = 2 To Range("B57").End(xlToRight).Column Step 2
    Set calcrange = Union(calcrange, Cells(57, c))
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm pretty new at VBA, so I wish I could zero in on what's going on. I'm getting an error, the debug is highlighting this line: /n `Dim c As Long
Set calcrange = Range("InvestmentOutlay")
For c = 2 To Range("B57").End(xlToRight).Column Step 2
    Set calcrange = Union(calcrange, Cells(57, c))
Next'
 This line here

`**Range("IRR").Formula = "=IRR(" & calcrange.Address & ")"`

Comment: Sorry that's confusing. So its the next line after the code you wrote, where it's inputting the calcrange variable in the IRR formula: 
`Range("IRR").Formula = "=IRR(" & calcrange.Address & ")"`

Comment: @jules325 - ahh - I should have read the code in more detail - I think you can change that line to say `Range("IRR").Formula = "=IRR((" & calcrange.Address & "))"` (But I would have expected that that would have given you a problem before, unless "InvestmentOutlay" was cell A57.)

Comment: @jules325 - yes, I have confirmed that the only way the existing `Range("IRR").Formula = "=IRR(" & calcrange.Address & ")"` would have given a meaningful answer previously is if the "InvestmentOutlay" range was referring to cell A57.  If it was anything else then it would have been treating InvestmentOutlay as your entire cashflow, and treating B57:x57 as the initial guess.  So I suspect you always should have had the brackets around the cashflow range.

Comment: Super close now. So it runs (Thanks so much), but when I highlight the IRR cell, its selecting one column further to the right than it should be; its picking up the percentage columns. I've been playing with the code but can't get it to pick up the correct columns. Its selecting B, D,F,G...I need it to select B,C,E,G...Any suggestions?

Comment: @jules325 - if your cashflow is "InvestmentOutlay" at time 0, B57 at time 1, C57 at time 2, E57 at time 3, etc, **and** there will always be something in at least B57 and C57, then you can use `Set calcrange = Union(Range("InvestmentOutlay"), Range("B57"))` `For c = 3 To Range("C57").End(xlToRight).Column Step 2` `...`

Comment: That seems to have done it. Thanks so much for your time and guidance.